# Euler Project - Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic, project

I know that it is a horrible question to ask at this forum since I do know the rules but at the moment I just do not know what the issue is here. So for anyone that has some spare time I would be very thankful if it could be answered. I tried to carry out the Euler Project exercise number 13: Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.

I know the logic that I have used behind it is not the best and later I managed to solve the problem using another method, but it still bothers me until today why does the following code not work:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LargeSum {

    public static ArrayList<String> addAll(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfResults) {

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        int singlesum = 0;
        int remainder = 0;

        for (int i = 49; i >= 0; i--) {

            System.out.println(remainder + "to rem");
            singlesum += remainder;

            for (ArrayList<Integer> list : listOfResults) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
                singlesum += list.get(i);
            }

            String lastChar = String.valueOf(singlesum);
            singlesum = 0;
            result.add(String.valueOf(lastChar.charAt(lastChar.length() - 1)));
            remainder = 0;

            if (lastChar.length() > 1) {
                remainder = Integer.parseInt(lastChar.substring(0, lastChar.length() - 1));
            }
        }

        if (remainder > 0)
            result.add(String.valueOf(remainder));


        return result;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> createLists() {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        String c =

                "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"
                        + "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538"
                        + "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629"
                        + "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250"
                        + "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676"
                        + "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757"
                        + "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738"
                        + "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318"
                        + "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276"
                        + "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951"
                        + "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331"
                        + "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178"
                        + "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407"
                        + "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828"
                        + "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390"
                        + "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586"
                        + "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829"
                        + "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938"
                        + "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604"
                        + "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145"
                        + "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721"
                        + "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045"
                        + "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412"
                        + "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692"
                        + "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483"
                        + "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691"
                        + "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209"
                        + "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126"
                        + "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515"
                        + "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954"
                        + "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581"
                        + "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984"
                        + "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030"
                        + "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332"
                        + "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210"
                        + "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085"
                        + "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271"
                        + "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375"
                        + "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307"
                        + "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275"
                        + "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271"
                        + "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526"
                        + "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962"
                        + "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141"
                        + "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403"
                        + "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470"
                        + "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583"
                        + "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470"
                        + "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533"
                        + "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822"
                        + "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774"
                        + "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236"
                        + "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967"
                        + "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522"
                        + "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501"
                        + "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715"
                        + "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381"
                        + "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539"
                        + "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635"
                        + "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903"
                        + "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922"
                        + "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457"
                        + "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519"
                        + "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672"
                        + "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308"
                        + "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581"
                        + "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500"
                        + "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327"
                        + "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789"
                        + "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886"
                        + "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337"
                        + "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731"
                        + "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504"
                        + "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622"
                        + "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724"
                        + "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818"
                        + "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852"
                        + "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090"
                        + "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786"
                        + "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039"
                        + "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116"
                        + "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411"
                        + "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714"
                        + "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096"
                        + "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297"
                        + "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252"
                        + "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011"
                        + "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791"
                        + "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699"
                        + "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078"
                        + "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353"
                        + "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535"
                        + "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954"
                        + "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280"
                        + "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608"
                        + "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197"
                        + "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617"
                        + "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516"
                        + "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4950; i += 50) {

            ArrayList<Integer> strings = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int j = i; j <= i + 49; j++) {
                strings.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c.charAt(j))));
            }

            results.add(strings);
        }

        return results;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results = createLists();
        System.out.println(addAll(results));

    }

}
```

The array should give me the number from the back one by one each digit of the number yet I do not get the answer to the question. I investigated this many times for smaller numbers (where it worked) and for only two numbers (and it worked) yet I cannot get the answer to the question (I always get another number as result not the designated Result: 5537376230).

Thanks to everybody that looks at the code.

Best regards,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main source of the issue lies in the fact that you hardcoded a lot of numerical values and thus can not really verify correctness in the middle steps. Especially bad idea is using single `String` instead of the array of `String[]` for your source data.

Anyway, if you re-check the [task](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13) you may find that the last numbers are:

```
...
72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516
20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722
53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690
```

while in your code you have:

```
                    + "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516"
                    + "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722";
```

So you just missed the last number and that spoils the result.

Sidenotes:

1. you don't really handle the top digits (your "top" digit is "55") properly which is a result of a lot of hardcoding but you probably already know that.
2. In java there is a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class that can solves this task easily. It is OK to write your own code for learning but for the real world task you should use a standard library unless you have a good reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you have a remainder left over, you add it to result as a string. But the digits in your `results` are reversed, so you also need to reverse the digits of the remainder.

It also looks like you've got an off-by-one error in the construction of your numbers. `i < 4950` should be `i < 5000` I think, since the 100th number starts at index 99 * 50 = 4950.